# no welcome intent in smart home action, is it normal

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

```
{
    "actions":[
        {
            "name":"actions.devices",
            "deviceControl":{

            },
            "fulfillment":{
                "conversationName":"automation"
            }
        }
    ],
    "conversations":{
        "automation":{
            "name":"automation",
            "url":"https://echo.goodk2.com:8000/GoogleHomeNew/konke.do"
        }
    }
}
```

It's my `action.json` as same as official smart home document. No welcome intent in it.

Everything is ok in mobile app. But test in Simulator, I say **"talk to smart k "**, it always responds **"Sorry, this action is not available in simulation"** (debug info is empty).

Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

For Smart Home actions, you don't talk directly to the Action. Instead, you use the normal Smart Home commands that Google Home understands to change the settings of the devices you control.

So this behavior sounds correct.

Comment: thank you for reply. sounds correct? sounds like you are not sure?

Comment: Well, I'm sure in the sense that I know that you don't define a welcome intent because other intents are triggered through direct commands.